# How to get unique values with frequency from List<String[]> in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, string, list

I want to get unique values from a `List<String[]>` and store them in a new list (or `HashMap<String, Integer>` where `String` is the unique value and `Integer` is its number of occurrences in the `List<String[]>`. How can I extract the unique values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Collectors.groupingBy`

```
Map<String, Long> map = abc.stream()
                           .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
                           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                       Collectors.counting()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 or above it's pretty easy. (Slight correction using the other answer)

```
List<String[]> abc = new ArrayList<>();
String[] string1 = {"123", "567"};
String[] string2 = {"123", "456"};
abc.add(string1);
abc.add(string2);

List<String> newList = abc.stream()
        .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
        .distinct()
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

Map<String, Long> hashMap = abc.stream()
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```